# Laravel on windows with Docker and Linux subsystem issue

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-sail

When running with Docker on Windows and using linux subsystem (WSL version 2) I can't get Docker to delete any container that I want to remove. Anyone else had this problem on windows and how to solve it?

See screenshot to how Docker responds:
[image: screenshot to how Docker responds]

Docker says "can't remove docker container, reason being that folder in question '/home/niko/laravel-app1', it's path can not be found.

however I can navigate to this folder via Explorer \wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\niko\laravel-app1

[image]

Anyone had any experience with this and how to get Docker to understand where the files actually are so it can delete the container when I ask it to do so?

Comment: Interesting, might be a windows vs. linux problem since the GUI application runs on windows. Try using the command line from within WSL to shut down this compose app.

Comment: what command line could I use? I'm using laravel sail, do you mean I should run "sail stop" or some other command?

Comment: In WSL switch to `/home/niko/laravel-app1` and run `docker-compose down`.